# Extensions and Limits of Inner Amenable Groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, operator-algebras, amenability

A group $G$ is said to be *inner amenable* if there exists a positive linear functional $m$ on $\ell^{\infty}(G)$ with $m(1)=1$ that is invariant under conjugation; i.e., $m(g^{-1}fg) = m(f)$ for every $f \in \ell^{\infty}(G)$, where $(g^{-1}fg)(x) = f(g^{-1}xg)$.

I have two related questions. First, if $(G_{n}, f_{ij})$ is a injective directed system of groups, does it follow that $\displaystyle \lim_{\rightarrow} G_n$ is inner amenable? Second, if $N$ is an inner amenable normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is inner amenable, does it follow that $G$ is inner amenable?

I know that these questions can be answered affirmatively if all the groups are actually amenable. But I am not sure about the inner amenable case.

Comment: $m(\delta_e)=0$ is missing from your definition. Otherwise $m(f)=f(e)$ always works. Also $N$ should be a normal subgroup for the definition to be meaningful.

Comment: The answer to the second question is clearly no: indeed if $N$ is nontrivial amenable, and $H$ is not inner amenable, then $H\times N$ is inner amenable but its quotient $(H\times N)/N=H$ is not inner amenable.

Comment: @YCor Even with that correction, the second question is vacuously true: if you assume that $G/N$ inner amenable, then clearly it is inner amenable. What I meant to ask is, if $N$ is a normal inner amenable subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is inner amenable, does it follow that $G$ is inner amenable. But I am having trouble seeing how you're example is a counterexample, because the quotient fails to be inner amenable.

Comment: Indeed there's a typo in your second question where you wrote $G/N$ twice. Would you edit with both corrections?

Comment: @YCor Should be fixed now.

Comment: @YCor So, any thoughts on the edit, or is the example you gave still a counterexample? I ask because I don't see how it is a counterexample to the edited question.

Comment: No, I'm not sure about the second question.

Answer (score 0):

The first question has a positive answer.

Indeed, let $m_n$ be conjugacy invariant on $G_n$ with $m_n(\{e\})=0$, and push it forward to $\mu_n$ on the direct limit. Then $\mu_n(\{e\})=0$ using injectivity, and $\mu_n$ is $G_n$-invariant. Hence any cluster point of $(\mu_n)$ is a conjugacy-invariant mean as required.